# Control eip/rip register via user input

Tags: c, gdb, eip

I have the exercise to control the input of the eip/rip register (in my case rip) arbitrarily. The following program is given:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VAR_SIZE 32

void output(int argc, char** argv) {
    char stack[VAR_SIZE];
    strcpy(stack, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", stack);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    output(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

We may use the debugger `gdb`. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag as this is clearly a "C" question. (C++ is a different language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the value of the RIP x86-64 register, you can use the following command in [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger):

```
set $rip = 20
```

This will set the value of the register to `20`.